# TensorFlow problem i have the required TF but still get an error

Tags: tensorflow

I created an env and imported `TensorFlow` but I get the error:

```
Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher
```

`TensorFlow` at this env is 2.3, so I don't know why I get this error.

[image]

Comment: Corrected code quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way to solve the problem is to create a new virtual environment
python 3.7
tesorflow 1.15.2

or uninstall any previously installed tensorflow and install 1.15.2
i'm not sure why this worked though.